# Ember update page title

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In my Ember app (actually mine is an engine within a host/parent app), I want to set the page title.

Now while I do

```
document.title = "Page title I want"
```

However, it gets overwritten by the host app i.e. what is set in the index.html

Where can I have the above code to set page title? Already tried adding in beforeModel, didTransition hooks, But that does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly recommend standardizing across your app and all engines on [ember-page-title](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-page-title). Which will allow you to add `{{page-title "Blog"}}` to a template. It has some additional features that are really nice when working in a larger app, but by delegating all of your title setting needs to a single addon you can have a standard API across your app and all engines for doing this task.

There are other addons that also serve this purpose, but [this RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/645) has movement towards making `ember-page-title` the default for new ember apps.

Comment: Thanks....and using this, we should be able to overwrite the page title set by host app (i.e. in index.html) by what we want (i.e. in my child engine)

Comment: Yes. Overwrite or append or prepend. Tons of options at the route template level.